# GitHub Error: RPC failed; curl 92 http/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8) | send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash, git-push

I am working on a project with a GitHub repo. I've been able to "add *", "commit" and "push" everything without a problem in the last 3 months. Now I downloaded a dataset containing about 12 GB of data and I have created a new folder for it.

I made some minor changes to the file that was already in the repo (for 3 months) and did "add *", "commit" and "git push".

After counting and compressing the objects, Git Bash throws up this error:

```
GitHub Error: RPC failed; curl 92 http/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
...
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

This is happening probably while writing the objects.

**I have tried the following:**

- set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
- set GIT_TRACE=1
- set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
- git config --global http.postBuffer 100000000
- git config --global https.postBuffer 100000000

After the latest attempt with all of the solutions mentioned above, this additional error was thrown after getting to 50% of writing the objects:

```
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
```

[A screenshot of the error on Git Bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGvCn.png)

So, my question is:
**1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I work around/solve this problem and successfully push my current workspace onto GitHub?**

Comment: Are you using a proxy, TLS middlebox, or an antivirus or firewall other than Windows Defender or Windows Firewall?  Those could all cause this problem.  You'd want to completely uninstall that software, restart, and then try again.

Comment: No. Like I said, I was able to do all these things without a problem about 3 months ago. I'm gonna try to delete the data and push it in bits (copy pasting smaller data pieces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by bypassing it with this tutorial:

https://githowto.com/removing_commits_from_a_branch

ATTENTION: Remember to make a copy of your code before proceeding. You can still go back since you aren't deleting commits but it's annoying when you have to follow the tutorial twice.

ALSO: The git hist command is an alias. This is the one I copied:

```
git config --global alias.hist "log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)[%ad]%C(reset) %C(green)[%h]%C(reset) | %C(red)%s %C(bold red){{%an}}%C(reset) %C(blue)%d%C(reset)' --graph --date=short"
```

LINK: https://gist.github.com/ecasilla/9669241

Answer (score 3):

> **1. Why is this happening?**

- Because you are trying to push a large file. (12 GB dataset)

> **2. How can I work around/solve this problem and successfully push
> my current workspace onto GitHub?**

- You can use [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) that replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com

Answer (score 2):

Following this step to clone the repo, it will solution this issue.

```bash
$ git clone http://github.com/large-project-repo.git --depth 1
$ cd large-project-repo
$ git fetch --unshallow
```